# Prove that $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ has no roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ has no roots.

I can see two ways of proving it.

The first one is to notice, that $x^5 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$. It has the only root 1. And it is not the root of $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$. So, $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ does not have roots.

Another way is to solve it as a palindromic polynomial. It does not have roots.

But is there any way to directly manipulate the expression to show that it is always greater than zero?

Comment: Can you show that it is always positive ? . That will prove it very easily. The case when x > 0 is obvious. So your task is to show for x < 0.

Comment: I imagine you mean that there are no real roots. Polynomials always have complex roots.

Comment: @MarkBennet  Yes of course. And that is probably what OP meant too. Didn't even see that he missed that word 'real'.

Answer (score 5):

$$f(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$$
if $x=1$ then $f(1)=5$ hense $f(1)>0$

if $x\neq 1$ then $f(x)=\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$

$(x^5-1)$ and $(x-1)$ have the same sign any $x$. Hence $f(x)>0$

Comment: Awesome solution!

Comment: Is this not slightly circular? Having the same sign shows that $f(x) \ge 0$ not that $f(x)>0$. To get a strict inequality, you need to know that $f(x) \ne 0$.

Comment: The case $x=1$ being considered before, in the case $x\neq 1$ it is obvious that $x^5-1\neq0$ hense $f(x)\neq0$.

Comment: @JJacquelin that's precisely my point. Your proof that $f(x) >0$ requires knowing that $f(x) \ne 0$, and therefore cannot be used to prove that $f(x) \ne 0$.

Comment: Read again my prove. Never $f(x)\neq 0$ is required.

Answer (score 4):

There is a theorem about positive polynomials being expressible as the sum of squares. Here $$f(x)=\left(x^2+\frac x2\right)^2 +\frac 34\left(x+\frac 23\right)^2+\frac 23$$

obtained by successively completing the square. Personally I prefer some of the simpler methods. For example one can observe that the roots of $f(x)$ are the complex fifth roots of $1$, so there are no real zeros.

Answer (score 3):

Another proof by contradiction.

Suppose $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ has a real root. Necessarily, $x<0$. Set $x=-t,\enspace t>0$. Rewrite the equation as
$$t^4-t^3+t^2-t=t(t-1)(t^2+1)=-1$$
It shows $t-1<0$, hence $\;0<t<1$.

On another hand, $\;t=\dfrac1{(1-t)(1+t^2)}=\dfrac1{1-t+t^2-t^3}$, and since $0<t<1$, we have $0<1-t+t^2-t^3<1-t+t^2=1-t(1-t)<1$, hence
$$t=\dfrac1{1-t+t^2-t^3}>1,\quad\text{contradiction}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that exists $a
 $ such that $$a^{4}+a^{3}+a^{2}+a+1=0.
 $$ Now it's obvious that $a\neq0
 $. So we have $$0=\frac{\left(a^{4}+a^{3}+a^{2}+a+1\right)}{a}=a^{3}+a^{2}+a+1+\frac{1}{a}
 $$ so $$a^{3}+a^{2}+a+1+\frac{1}{a}=a^{4}+a^{3}+a^{2}+a+1\Longrightarrow\frac{1}{a}=a^{4}\Rightarrow1=a^{5}
 $$ so we have $$a=1
 $$ and this is absurd. Now since $f\left(x\right)=x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1
 $ is a continuous function, to see if it is positive it is sufficient see what happens at one point.